# Error While minifying app stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, meteor

I get the problem when I run meteor to build my project.

I checked the github issue that I may need to comment out this line

```
behavior: url(#default#VML);
```

but I don't know which file the line in?

```
While minifying app stylesheet:
   path.js:8:11: Path must be a string. Received null
   at assertPath (path.js:8:11)
   at Object.posix.relative (path.js:496:3)
   at pathRelative (packages/minifier-css.js:449:30)
   at packages/minifier-css.js:408:31
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:139:11)
   at packages/minifier-css.js:365:7
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:139:11)
   at rewriteRules (packages/minifier-css.js:342:5)
   at Object.CssTools.rewriteCssUrls (packages/minifier-css.js:328:5)
   at packages/minifier-css.js:298:16
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:139:11)
   at Object.CssTools.mergeCssAsts (packages/minifier-css.js:275:7)
   at mergeCss (packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:231:33)
   at CssToolsMinifier.processFilesForBundle
   (packages/minifier-postcss/plugin/minify-css.js:109:18)
```

My meteor list is here. I think it is possible that the leaflet cause the problem.

```
accounts-password                       1.3.2  Password support for accounts
anbuselvan:meteor-toggle-switch         1.0.2  Meteor Toggle Switch
artwells:queue                          0.1.2  job queue for meteor, using mo...
aslagle:reactive-table                  0.8.38  A reactive table designed for...
bdunnette:leaflet-draw                  1.0.5* Adds support for drawing and e...
blaze-html-templates                    1.0.5  Compile HTML templates into re...
brylie:leaflet-heat                     0.1.0* A tiny, simple and fast Leafle...
check                                   1.2.4  Check whether a value matches ...
d3js:d3                                 3.5.8  D3 (official): A JavaScript vi...
ejson                                   1.0.13  Extended and Extensible JSON ...
email                                   1.1.18  Send email messages
herrhelms:meteor-leaflet-markercluster  0.0.2  L.MarkerClusterGroup by @danze...
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3             1.2.89  Bootstrap-styled accounts-ui ...
insecure                                1.0.7  (For prototyping only) Allow a...
iron:router                             1.0.13  Routing specifically designed...
jquery                                  1.11.10  Manipulate the DOM using CSS...
juliancwirko:postcss                    1.2.0  Minifier for Meteor with PostC...
juliancwirko:s-alert                    3.2.0  Simple and fancy notifications...
logging                                 1.1.16  Logging facility.
meteor-base                             1.0.4  Packages that every Meteor app...
mobile-experience                       1.0.4  Packages for a great mobile us...
momentjs:moment                         2.16.0  Moment.js (official): parse, ...
mongo                                   1.1.14  Adaptor for using MongoDB and...
nimble:restivus                         0.8.11  Create authenticated REST API...
postrednik:meteor-rangeslider           0.1.0  wrapper for Ion.RangeSlider
random                                  1.0.10  Random number generator and u...
reactive-var                            1.0.11  Reactive variable
reload                                  1.1.11  Reload the page while preserv...
session                                 1.1.7  Session variable
shell-server                            0.2.1  Server-side component of the `...
spacebars                               1.0.13  Handlebars-like template lang...
standard-minifier-js                    1.2.1  Standard javascript minifiers ...
tracker                                 1.1.1  Dependency tracker to allow re...
tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker         4.17.37_1  Bootstrap 3 DateTime picke...
twbs:bootstrap                          3.3.6  The most popular front-end fra...
u2622:persistent-session                0.4.4  Persistently store Session dat...
zhenya:forkme                           0.0.1  Github fork me CSS ribbon base...
```

Comment: Stack trace says `path.js line 8`.

Comment: No, I already checked the file.

Comment: Post path.js here.

Comment: This is likely due to one of your packages using an illegal unquoted url in a CSS `url` statement. Please add the output of `meteor list` to your question (and if you are using npm packages that have CSS, please list them as well).

Comment: Well, [this issue comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7446#issuecomment-236550776) states that this is probably it. You can try the `leaflet.heat` npm package instead (as the Meteor package is basically a wrapper for it).

Comment: I tried it. If I removed these leaflet packages it works. But I can't find any other leaflet packages to replace these packages.